# Please help to solve my equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, algebra, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I spent more than around 15hrs trying to find values of two equations but no result comes out yet.

My two equations are:

```
(1.8778e21)=((n*x)/(n+0.0080))(1-exp(-5400*(x+0.0080)))

(3.3658e21)=((n*x)/(n+0.0189))(1-exp(-5400*(x+0.0189)))
```

I used `sym`  and `solve(equ,var)` in MATLAB but

```
x =

[ empty sym ]
```

Do you have any idea please because I need urgently

Answer (score 0):

The equations are inconsistent, so there is no solution for these.

And hence the result: `[ empty sym ]`

Comment: can I know why they are inconsistent please?

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi why do you think it has a solution ? I can't really explain this here. You may want to ask a question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: @HishamAlghamdi If you draw surfaces corresponding to the two equations as functions of n and x, they may not intersect: if they don't there is no exact solution (but there may be a least-squares solution).